# How to count the number of times a digit appears at the beginning of each number in a file? (python)

Tags: python

I am trying to count the number of times 1,2,3,...,9 appear at the beginning of each number in a file. This is how my code goes:

```
DECIMAL_NUM='123456789'

def main():
    #get the file name from the user
    file_name=str(input("Enter a file name: "))

    #open the file to read
    input_file= open(str(file_name),'r')
    #reads the first line of the file
    line=input_file.readline().strip()

    one=0
    two=0
    three=0
    four=0
    five=0
    six=0
    seven=0
    eight=0
    nine=0
    i=0

    while line!="":

        if line[0]==DECIMAL_NUM[0]:
            one+=1            
        elif line[0]==DECIMAL_NUM[1]:
            two+=1
        elif line[0]==DECIMAL_NUM[2]:
            three+=1
        elif line[0]==DECIMAL_NUM[3]:
            four+=1
        elif line[0]==DECIMAL_NUM[4]:
            five+=1
        elif line[0]==DECIMAL_NUM[5]:
            six+=1
        elif line[0]==DECIMAL_NUM[6]:
            seven+=1
        elif line[0]==DECIMAL_NUM[7]:
            eight+=1
        elif line[0]==DECIMAL_NUM[8]:
            nine+=1           
        line=input_file.readline().strip()
        i+=1
    input_file.close()
    print(one)
    print(two)    
main()
```

I am also counting how many numbers are there in the file, so that I can calculate percentage of appearance of each digit. I think my codes are a little bit wordy and there might be a better way to do it. The input file has the following numbers:

```
1292

1076

188040

1579

3510

2597

3783

64690
```

For some reason, I am getting the number of times 1 is appearing as 1, when it should be 5. Could someone please give me some pointers? Thanks

Comment: well line[0] is the first character and DECIMAL_NUM[0]=1. So, one counts the number of times 1 appears at the beginning of line. Isn't it?

Comment: Does the input file have blank lines?

Comment: Well, I copied and pasted it and there are a lot of empty space in the  txt file. So, there may be blank lines. Not sure how to find it though.

Comment: @cobra you can check if a line is empty by calling `.strip()` on it (which will remove all whitespace from it, including newlines and tabs) and then checking whether the result evaluates to `False` via `if line.strip(): ...`. If the line is empty (`""`), this check will return `False`.

Comment: @cobra now keep that in mind, and look at your loop again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of approaching this task:

```
# Get non-empty lines from input file:
relevant_lines = [line for line in open(file_name).readlines() if line.strip()]
# Count them:
num_lines = len(relevant_lines)

import defaultdict
# If a key does not exist in a defaultdict when adding a value for it,
# it will be added with a default value for the given data type
# (0 in case of int):
d = defaultdict(int)

# Iterate through lines; get first character of line
# and increment counter for this character by one in defaultdict:
for line in relevant_lines:
    d[line[0]] += 1

# Print results:
for key, value in d.items():
    print(k + ' appears ' + value + ' times in file.')
```

If you are not allowed to use `dict`s, here's how to fix your code:

```
DECIMAL_NUM='123456789'

def main():
    # Get file name from user
    file_name = input("Enter a file name: ")

    # Open the file to read, and get a list of all lines:
    lines = open(file_name, 'r').readlines()

    one = 0
    two = 0
    three = 0
    four = 0
    five = 0
    six = 0
    seven = 0
    eight = 0
    nine = 0

    for line in lines:

        if line.strip(): # Check if line is not empty

            if line[0] == DECIMAL_NUM[0]:
                one += 1            
            elif line[0] == DECIMAL_NUM[1]:
                two += 1
            elif line[0] == DECIMAL_NUM[2]:
                three += 1
            elif line[0] == DECIMAL_NUM[3]:
                four += 1
            elif line[0] == DECIMAL_NUM[4]:
                five += 1
            elif line[0] == DECIMAL_NUM[5]:
                six += 1
            elif line[0] == DECIMAL_NUM[6]:
                seven += 1
            elif line[0] == DECIMAL_NUM[7]:
                eight += 1
            elif line[0] == DECIMAL_NUM[8]:
                nine += 1

    print(one)
    print(two)

main()
```

Comment: Your solution may be right. But, I haven't done dict (I am assuming it is dictionary) yet. So, can't use it.

Comment: @cobra Check my updated answer, I've included a solution based on what you came up with.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did check it and it is giving the right answer. I need to do some more work on it. Thanks again for working on my problem.

Comment: @cobra You are welcome. You might want to consider accepting my answer if it solves your problem :) Also, let me know if you have any questions about the solutions I posted. I'll be happy to add more information to my post.

Comment: @cobra Also, +1 for "I need to do some more work on it." That's the spirit! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You code is fine.  It's your data file that's giving you problem.  Remove the blank lines and your program should give you the right results.

```
1292
1076
188040
1579
3510
2597
3783
64690
```

After you processed the first line, the next line is read.  But that's a blank line and your while loop ends.

Comment: You are right. Instead of copying and pasting, I just created a new file with the same name and data in it and my codes are giving me a better answer. Thanks a lot for working with me.

Comment: "better answer"? I ran your code and it seems fine for me.  What other issues are you having? I'm learning Python as well.

Comment: It is giving the right answer. Previously, I had all my numbers in a column and that is why all the problems were happening. The original file has all the numbers in a row, and now everything is working fine. Thanks for your help though.